# How to prevent new line when enter is pressed in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

for a multiline textinput, when user press enter key, I want to achieve the goals:

- keep textinput focus when user press enter key.
- prevent add a new line.

i have't see any props what can do it, anyone has ideas?

react-native version is 0.28+, need supports ios and android.

Comment: @Ctc this is not a duplicate. Your issue is for the web, not react native.

Comment: Have the same exact issue. Cleaning up the value of textinput inside the text change callback causes flicker not only in editor itself but also changes hints etc so it is very obvious something is going on - not a good user experience. Still searching for better solution. This is NOT A DUP.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I also want to block a change.

Comment: @Noitidart check my answer below

Answer (score 26):

In TextInput passing the props

`blurOnSubmit = {true}` and then in onBlur props focus the textInput field  using ref,these two will prevents from entering a new line and the focus is retained on the text input field. If you want only to prevent the user from entering a newline `blurOnSubmit = {true}` is sufficient

The drawback here is you can see keyboard hides for a moment then pops up. 
Its bit like a hack. Hope someone can come up with another or improvise this

Comment: Thanks @Tharzeez for brignging this to my attention. This indeed is a hack, I will test it out and let you know how it works. What did you test on Android? iOS? Both?

Comment: i tested on ios, i will check with android and update

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't get a chance to test yet, but I will also let you know when I test.

Comment: Very cool thank you! I will try and see too. Ideally there is a way to do it without the keyboard flickering. Did you try a controlled component and try to block "enter" key?

Comment: @Noitidart i didnt try that yet, will try that soon

Comment: I tried the controlled component and when i hit enter it puts a new line, and because its controlled it then removes that new line. Its ugly to see this flicker. Btw your hack works, i forgot to mention, excuse that. It's nice but we either deal with flicker of keyboard, or flicker of new line via controlled. :(

Comment: This does change behaviour though. If you don't want to blur the keyboard and still want to capture the enter key, what's the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup your `TextInput` with multiline and blurOnSubmit to false.
This will keep the keyboard and allow multiline in the input.

And use the onKeyPress props only for sending a message.

```
onKeyPress({ nativeEvent: { key: keyValue } }) {
    if (keyValue === "Enter") this.sendMessage();
}
```

with

```
onMessageInputChange(message) {
    this.setState({
        message,
    });
}
```

This should work in both Android and iOS.

```
            <TextInput
                value={message}
                onChangeText={this.onMessageInputChange}
                onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
                returnKeyType="send"
                blurOnSubmit={false}
                multiline
            />
```

Comment: don't think this prevents from adding a new line

Comment: `blurOnSubmit` value is false for multiline fields by default

Answer (score -18):

Here is example:

```js
$(".Post_Description_Text").keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("New line entered");
  }
});
```

```css
.Post_Description_Text {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="comment_text" id="comment_text" class="Post_Description_Text"></textarea>
```