# How to disable inserting new line in multiline TextInput when enter is pressed in React Native

Tags: react-native, textinput

I want to build a chat app which is multiline TextInput and user can send the message when the enter is pressed. However it seems when the user press enter, the new line will be inserted anyway which give the user a bad experience.

I have tried [How to prevent new line when enter is pressed in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068675/how-to-prevent-new-line-when-enter-is-pressed-in-react-native) but the new line still persists after the user hit Enter in the keyboard. 
I also tried to trim the text when `onChangeText` is fired, but it seems the new line is still inserted. I know it works when `blurOnSubmit=true`, but I want to keep the keyboard open when user hits enter.

Comment: You could use an event listener on keydown of the enter button key code

Comment: I tried, but in my code onKeyPress is fired later than onChangeText, so the new line is already inserted then onKeyPress is called.

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but how about deleting the last character (i.e. the new line) onKeyPress as a workaround?

Comment: As I said, the new line first inserted then `onKeyPress` is fired. If I delete the new line in `onKeyPress`, the user will notice the flash of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

Just add this to TextInput -> blurOnSubmit={true}

For example:

```
<TextInput multiline={true} numberOfLines={1} blurOnSubmit={true} />
```

Comment: the question says they want to keep the keyboard open when the user hits enter, blueOnSubmit={true} will dismiss it

Answer (score 1):

You can check for a line break in the updated string that we get from `onChangeText` and accordingly update the state. By doing this, the keyboard will not get dismissed.

Snack with the implementation [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/multiline-but-dont-dismiss-the-keyboard)

The `onChangeText` function should look like this.

```js
// function to handle onChangeText
const handleTextChange = (text: string) => {
  if (text.length) {
    let checkLineBreak = /\r|\n/.exec(text[text.length - 1]);
    if (checkLineBreak) {
      console.log(
        'Execute Something which you want to when user presses the enter key'
      );
      ToastAndroid.show('Enter Pressed keyboard not dimissed', 3000);
    }
  }

  SetMessage(text.trimEnd());
};
```