# How to add a new native component to react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, custom-component, react-native-textinput

**Situation:** We've used `patch-package` to the `react-native` package in order to disable adding a new line when the user presses `return` in multiline `TextInput`.

**Problem:** We only want this behavior of `TextInput` in one section of the app but not anywhere else.

**Question:** How should I create a new component that mimics the original `TextInput`? In the end, I'd like to have two components named `TextInput` and `OriginalTextInput`. If the `multiline` prop is true, the former should not add a new line when pressing return and the opposite for the latter.

I'm all ears on other ways of solving this problem as long as it doesn't involve using the props of `TextInput`.

Comment: Show the sample code you did

Comment: @sojin it's one line edit to `textInputShouldChangeText` function of this file: `react-native/Libraries/Text/TextInput/RCTBaseTextInputView.m` that disables adding a new line when pressing return in multiline `TextInput`

Comment: Can you try this?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49176263/2247055

Comment: @FreakyCoder unfortunately, your link involves using the props of `TextInput`

Comment: Why don't you want to utilize the props?

Comment: I don't know why do you need something like this but you can create your own custom text input directly from iOS and Android with the Native Modules. I do not suggest that just for this feature.

https://mobilityquotient.com/article/creating-a-native-bridge-in-react-native

This link should show you a way how to build a native module.