# React Native: how to prevent adding new line on Enter button press on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, textinput

could you help me understand how in React Native application to prevent adding new line on Android in native files? On iOS I made it to work by modifying function `textInputShouldChangeText` in file `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text/TextInput/RCTBaseTextInputView.m`.

I want to do the same on Android, already found few native files where I can add changes (inside `node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textInput`), but I can't get logs from that files in Android Studio, it feels like my changes inside these files are not applied in bundle.

Could you hint me what I'm doing wrong?

I'm expecting inside multiline TextInput to press Enter and to make textInput don't add new line, stay at the same line and receive event in onKeyPress prop.

Comment: First of all, are you making amends to the files in node_modules via patching or just directly? Files within Node_modules will change based on your package.json files, and if there are new packages etc You shouldn't be directly editing them.

I'll flag an existing answer that I think will help you for your original issue, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent new line when enter is pressed in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068675/how-to-prevent-new-line-when-enter-is-pressed-in-react-native)

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you for your help. 
Regarding changing the files, I understand that I will need to make a patch for applying the changes after all re-installing the  modules. The issue is that I don’t see even immediate direct changes in native files (tried to add java logs)
Regarding your second question: I saw that topic and it doesn’t help me as I need to have `blurOnSubmit={false}` according to the logic of app.